# Given the characteristic equation of A.Find equation for B.

Tags: linear-algebra, characteristic-functions

Given that $\chi_A(x)=x^3-ax^2+bx-c$

Find $\chi_B(x)$ For:

a)B=A-2I

b)$B=A^2$

For a) would you put x+2 in for x in the $\chi_A(x)$. As Det(XI-B)=Det(XI+2I-A)= det((X+2)I-A)

And b: Im not sure how to do but you have to square the eigenvalues?

Comment: Yes: you have to square the eigenvalues, so that you need to find the polynomial whose roots are $\alpha^2, \beta^2 , \gamma^2$, where $\alpha, \beta , \gamma$ are the roots of $\chi_A(x)$.

Comment: See the 11th and 12th slides [at this link](http://www.math.cmu.edu/~mlavrov/arml/13-14/polynomials-02-09-14.pdf) for a hint on how to do it.

Comment: so It would be (x^3−ax^2+bx−c)((x^3+ax^2-bx+c) then replace X^2 with x's?

Comment: Yes: this is exactly what you have to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $A^3-aA^2+bA-cI=0$ you get
$$
               A(A^2+bI)=aA^2+cI
$$
Squaring both sides,
$$
               A^2(A^4+2bA^2+b^2I)=a^2A^4+2acA^2+c^2I \\
               B(B^2+2bB+b^2I)=a^2B^2+2acB+c^2I \\
                B^3+2bB^2+b^2B-a^2B^2-2acB-c^2I=0 \\
                B^3+(2b-a^2)B^2+(b^2-2ac)B-c^2I=0.
$$